# What does photon noise mean in digital image processing or computer vision?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, noise

From [this link](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-0-387-31439-6_482):

> Photon noise, also known as Poisson noise, is a basic form of uncertainty associated with the measurement of light, inherent to the quantized nature of light and the independence of photon detections.

I couldn’t understand,

> … and the independence of photon detections.

What did the author actually mean by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately at a fundamental level, an image signal as captured by a digital sensor is obtained by integrating the energy transmitted by the photons of the light wave.

If you are imaging a bright scene, there will be a large enough number of photons hitting the detector that this effect will not be detectable, but if the sensor is operating in a dark environment, individual photons may be detected and counted, and the number of photons that have hit a cell of the detector as a function of time is modeled as a [Poisson random process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Interpreted_as_a_counting_process).